# How can i simply convert the following code of accessing the JSON from Assets to JSON URL parsing?

Tags: android, json

This is actually an android application for taking quiz. The question and it's options are displayed in a textview, and radio buttons respectively. Also the correct answer is also there in JSON that is checked to calculate the score. I need help in changing the JSON access from Assets directory to a URL.

```
public class Test extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView txt_question,txt_timer,txt_score;
    RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3,rb4,rb5;
    RadioGroup rg;
    Button btn_skip, btn_next;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    public int flag = 0;
    public int score;
    private JSONArray jsonArray;
    private String rightAnswer;
    CountDownTimer cT;
    int time;

    Dialog restartdialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        // Creating new JSON Parser

        initializeScreen();
        sb = readJsonFromAssets();
        String myjsonstring = sb.toString();
        txt_timer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
        time=(int)getIntent().getExtras().getInt("timer");
        score=0;
        btn_next=(Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        rg=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        restartdialog= new Dialog(Test.this);
        restartdialog.setContentView(R.layout.restart);
        restartdialog.setTitle("Want to try again?");
        Button btnyes=(Button)restartdialog.findViewById(R.id.yes);
        btnyes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    flag = 0;
                    reInflateView(jsonArray.getJSONObject(flag));
                    txt_score.setText("" + score);
                    score = 0;
                    restartdialog.dismiss();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        time = (int) getIntent().getExtras().getInt("timer");

        Button btnno=(Button)restartdialog.findViewById(R.id.no);
        btnno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String selectedAns = "";
                try {

                    if (flag < jsonArray.length()) {
                        switch (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                            case R.id.option1:
                                selectedAns = "Option1";
                                flag++;
                                cT.start();
                                break;
                            case R.id.option2:
                                selectedAns = "Option2";
                                flag++;
                                cT.start();
                                break;
                            case R.id.option3:
                                selectedAns = "Option3";
                                flag++;
                                cT.start();
                                break;
                            case R.id.option4:
                                selectedAns = "Option4";       // These are the options that are to be selected.
                                flag++;
                                cT.start();
                                break;
                            case R.id.option5:
                                selectedAns = "Option5";
                                flag++;
                                cT.start();
                                break;
                            default:
                                Toast.makeText(Test.this,"Please Select one option or skip to next question",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                        }
                        if (rightAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(selectedAns)) {
                            ++score;
                            txt_score.setText("" + score);
                        }

                        if (flag == jsonArray.length()) {
                            restartdialog.setTitle("You Scored "+score+" out of "+flag+", Want to try again?");
                            restartdialog.setCancelable(false);
                            restartdialog.show();
                            score = 0;
                        } else {
                            reInflateView(jsonArray.getJSONObject(flag));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                rg.clearCheck();
            }
        });
        btn_skip=(Button) findViewById(R.id.skip);
        btn_skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    time=(int)getIntent().getExtras().getInt("timer");
                    if(flag == jsonArray.length()-1){
                        restartdialog.setTitle("You Scored "+score+" out of "+flag+", Want to try again?");
                        restartdialog.setCancelable(false);
                        restartdialog.show();
                        flag=0;
                        score = 0;
                    } else {
                        flag++;
                        reInflateView(jsonArray.getJSONObject(flag));
                    }
                    cT.start();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                rb1.setEnabled(true);
                rb2.setEnabled(true);
                rb3.setEnabled(true);
                rb4.setEnabled(true);
                rb5.setEnabled(true);
                btn_next.setEnabled(true);
                rg.clearCheck();
            }

        });
        cT =  new CountDownTimer(time*1000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                txt_timer.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                txt_timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {

                txt_timer.setText("Time over for this question");
                txt_timer.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                rb1.setEnabled(false);
                rb2.setEnabled(false);
                rb3.setEnabled(false);
                rb4.setEnabled(false);
                rb5.setEnabled(false);
                btn_next.setEnabled(false);
            }
        };
        cT.start();


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);
            jsonArray = jsonObjMain.getJSONArray("questions");
            reInflateView(jsonArray.getJSONObject(flag));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        txt_score.setText(""+score);
    }



    private StringBuffer readJsonFromAssets() {

        int type=(int)getIntent().getExtras().getInt("timer");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            if(type==40) {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("queshard.json")));
            }
            else if(type==30)
            {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("quesmedium.json")));
            }
            else
            {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("queseasy.json")));
            }
            String temp;
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(temp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb;
    }

    private void initializeScreen() {
        txt_question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ques);
        rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option1);
        rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option2);
        rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option3);
        rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option4);
        rb5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option5);
        txt_score=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    }

    private void reInflateView(JSONObject jsonObj) {
        try {
            String question = jsonObj.getString("ques");
            String optionA = jsonObj.getString("Option1");
            String optionB = jsonObj.getString("Option2");
            String optionC = jsonObj.getString("Option3");
            String optionD = jsonObj.getString("Option4");
            String optionE = jsonObj.getString("Option5");
            rightAnswer = jsonObj.getString("correct_answer_index");
            txt_question.setText(""+(flag+1)+") "+question);

            rb1.setOnClickListener(null);
            rb2.setOnClickListener(null);
            rb3.setOnClickListener(null);
            rb4.setOnClickListener(null);
            rb5.setOnClickListener(null);

            rb1.setText(optionA);
            rb2.setText(optionB);
            rb3.setText(optionC);
            rb4.setText(optionD);
            rb5.setText(optionE);

            rb1.setChecked(false);
            rb1.setOnClickListener(this);
            rb2.setChecked(false);
            rb2.setOnClickListener(this);
            rb3.setChecked(false);
            rb3.setOnClickListener(this);
            rb4.setChecked(false);
            rb4.setOnClickListener(this);
            rb5.setChecked(false);
            rb5.setOnClickListener(this);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Test.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.back);
        dialog.setTitle("Are You Sure?");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Button btnok=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
        btnok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        Button btncancel=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        btncancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

---

The following is the JSON file on ABC_URL that is to be fetched from a URL instead of assets file:

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "ques": "Super class of every class?",
      "Option1": "class",
      "Option2": "Class",
      "Option3": "Object",
      "Option4": "Java",
      "Option5": "None of the above",
      "correct_answer_index": "Option3"
    },

    {
      "ques": "Which class cannot be a subclass in java?",
      "Option1": "Abstract class",
      "Option2": "Parent class",
      "Option3": "Final class",
      "Option4": "All of the above",
      "Option5": "None of the above",
      "correct_answer_index": "Option3"
    },

    {
      "ques": " Suspend thread can be revived by using",
      "Option1": "Start() method",
      "Option2": "Suspend() method",
      "Option3": "resume() method",
      "Option4": "yield() method",
      "Option5": "None of the above",
      "correct_answer_index": "Option3"
    },

    {
      "ques": "Runnable is : ",
      "Option1": "Class",
      "Option2": "Method",
      "Option3": "Variable",
      "Option4": "Interface",
      "Option5": "None of the above",
      "correct_answer_index": "Option4"
    },

    {
      "ques": "Which collection class associates values witch keys, and orders the keys according to their natural order ?",
      "Option1": "java.util.HashSet",
      "Option2": "java.util.LinkedList",
      "Option3": "java.util.TreeMap",
      "Option4": "java.util.SortedSet",
      "Option5": "None of the above",
      "correct_answer_index": "Option3"
    },

    {
      "ques": "Which method is used to perform DML statements in JDBC?",
      "Option1": "execute()",
      "Option2": "executeUpdate()",
      "Option3": "executeQuery()",
      "Option4": "executeNonQuery()",
      "Option5": "None of the above",
      "correct_answer_index": "Option2"
    },

    {
      "ques": "Which of the following below are valid isolation levels in J2EE?",
      "Option1": "TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED",
      "Option2": "TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE",
      "Option3": "Only A",
      "Option4": "Only B",
      "Option5": "Both A and B",
      "correct_answer_index": "Option5"
    },

    {
      "ques": "Which methods are utilized to control the access to an object in multi threaded programming?",
      "Option1": "Asynchronized methods",
      "Option2": "Synchronized methods",
      "Option3": "Serialized methods",
      "Option4": "All of the above",
      "Option5": "None of the above",
      "correct_answer_index": "Option2"
    },

    {
      "ques": "Program which executes applet is known as :",
      "Option1": "Applet engine",
      "Option2": "Virtual machine",
      "Option3": "JVM",
      "Option4": "JRE",
      "Option5": "None of the above",
      "correct_answer_index": "Option1"
    },

    {
      "ques": "Which statement is static and synchronized in JDBC API?",
      "Option1": "executeQuery()",
      "Option2": "executeUpdate()",
      "Option3": "getConnection()",
      "Option4": "prepareCall()",
      "Option5": "None of the above",
      "correct_answer_index": "Option3"
    },

    {
      "ques": "The JDBC-ODBC bridge is",
      "Option1": "Multithreaded",
      "Option2": "Singlethreaded",
      "Option3": "Asyncthread",
      "Option4": "All of the above",
      "Option5": "None of the above",
      "correct_answer_index": "Option1"
    },

    {
      "ques": "All raw data types should be read and uploaded to the database as an array of :",
      "Option1": "Int",
      "Option2": "Char",
      "Option3": "Boolean",
      "Option4": "Double",
      "Option5": "Byte",
      "correct_answer_index": "Option5"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: there where u´ve got `new InputStreamReader(` use `Url.openStream` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method to parse the Json by passing the url in the method:

```
public String executeRequest(String url, Activity context) {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    TAG = NetworkRequest.class.getSimpleName();

    Log.i(TAG, "WEBSERVICE URL--------------- " + url);

    final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
    Constants.CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams,
    Constants.SOCKET_TIME_OUT);

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    httpGet.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

    httpGet.addHeader("Cache-Control", "No-Cache");

    String serverResponse = null;
    try {

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new 
        BasicResponseHandler();
        serverResponse = responseHandler.handleResponse(httpResponse);

        int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

            Log.i(TAG, " Successfull, STATUS CODE: " + statusCode);

            return serverResponse;

        } else {

            Log.i(TAG, "Failure, STATUS CODE: " + statusCode);
            return null;

        }

    } catch (MalformedChallengeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {

        exception.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    return serverResponse;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer prashant... But still not working... :( :( Maybe if i show you the whole code, then you can help... I'll try to do it ASAP!!! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ? Are you getting any exception ? Please post it if any.